# How to develop and add function in python that adds two points together

Tags: function

So I have to make a function in python that adds two multidimentsional points together and outputs the new coordinates.

I start with

```
class point:
  def__int__(self,dim,data):
    self.dim=dim
    self.data=[]
    for i in range(dim):
      self.data.append(float(data[i]))
```

this part is giving in the assignment code and cannot be changed.
the required function must be typed as so
p1.add(p2)

the function I am attempting to write currently looks like this

```
def add (self, p2):
  sum=0
  for i in p1.data:
    for i in p2.data:
      sum+=(p1.data[i])+(p2.data[i])
  return sum
```

I then define two points

```
p1=point(2,[3,4])
p2=point(2,[6,7])
```

and attempt to run the function:

```
p1.add(p2)
```

then I get error that

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

my expected output should be a point with the coord.

```
(9,11)
```

Please help I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in p2.data` iterates over the elements, not indices,  of p2.data, which are floats, not integers.

Try

```
for a, b in zip(self.data, p2.data)
```

and see how far you get. It will iterate through the coordinates together.

For example, the first iteration has `a` as `self.data[0]` and `b` as `p2.data[0]`.

The next iteration has `a` as `self.data[1]` and `b` as `p2.data[1]`

Comment: hmm, I am not sure if my question was clear. I have 2 defined points and just need to add them together so I need i (in posted code) to serve as the x and y coords and have the loop add the x's and y's together to give me [9,11] as the final product. I tried your solution but it is still saying need integer, not tuple